# In program while printing the count of the word: "the", from a .txt file containing sentences gives a count=0 even when count of "the" is not zero

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ifstream fin;
    char ch[30];
    int count = 0;
    fin.open("story.txt");
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin>>ch;
        if(ch == "the" || ch == "The")
        {
        count++;
        cout<<" "<<ch;
        }

     }

    fin.close();
    cout<<" Number of the's in the file : "<<count;

    
}
```

> Not supposed to use strcompi() function.(or any other functions that could help compare the "ch" with "the")

> The count gives zero output because the if condition doesn't work

> This is my code, what could be the problem over here.**

Comment: This cannot be done in C++ (or C) without using functions. Note that you already violated this restriction by calling `open` for the `ifstream`. Furthermore comparing char arrays won't work, if you use `==`, since this only compares memory locations of the arrays.

Comment: Welcome! Consider being a bit more elaborate on what are you trying to achieve, what went wrong in your opinion and so forth. Also note that this style of coding is not really of C++. Consider using standard library containers instead of arrays.

Comment: Have you tried using `std::string` instead of a char array?

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Also, `main` is a function :-)

Comment: `operator >>` and `<<` are functions.  `fin.close()` is a function.  And if you were to use `std::string`, using `==` would be a function call.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare char arrays with `==`, but you can with `std::string`.

Change

```
char ch[30];
```

to

```
std::string ch;
```

Comment: Yes it worked great thank you. Kindly explain your answer to me if you can.

Comment: @SaadRahman The explanation is that your program reads and inspects words. Words are called strings. And `std::string` is the standard c++ way of using strings. If you use `std::string` instead of `char[]` arrays like you had, everything about string manipulation is easier. `char[]` arrays are more like C-programming and more difficult to work with correctly, as you have seen with the incorrect attempt at comparison which led to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `char ch[30];` with `std::string ch`, it looks like it would work. Maybe with some minor adjustments.

The reason why it doesn't work is that `ch == "the"` tests whether `char ch[30]`, decayed as a pointer, points to the same memory location as the "the" literal. And it doesn't.

If you use a `std::string`, the `operator==` for the `std::string` will be called and it will do the right thing: compare the two strings.

Comment: std : :string ch worked but I can't understand the meaning of it.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_string_handling

Comment: Thank you! Looking into it.